#  HtmlUnit's WebClient fails on second identical loadWebResponse() call

Tags: java, servlets, junit, htmlunit

I'm attempting to write tests for a very long and kludgy "getPost" method in a webapp I'm working on for my job. I'm using `JUnit`, `HtmlUnit`, and Jetty's `ServletTester` to approximate sending a request to a servlet and receiving a response. I've managed to get it mostly working, but I'm having a problem. I'm trying to test the login functionality. If the user logs in successfully, the server should send some JSON back to the client with the user's information. If the user is already logged in, the server should send back "result": "failure" and an error message.

My problem comes when I try to test the second requirement. I can log in successfully, and get the correct data back. However, when I try to send the request again, it returns 404: not found. I tried breaking the code up into different tests, but I have to be able to call login twice in order to test the second requirement. Later tests in the JUnit file run just fine, and the servlet is staying connected the same time. I tried making a second, identical request, but that also failed. I've searched the internet to no avail. In short, I'm stumped.

Here's what I'm working with (unnecessary code has been edited out):

```
//In MyFunServlet class:
private final static String USERID_ATTRIBUTENAME = "userid";
void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String action = request.getParameter("opt");
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if(action != null){
       Long userId = (Long)session.getAttribute(USERID_ATTRIBUTENAME);
       if(userId != null){
           //do stuffz
       } else {
           if(action.equals("login")) {
               User user = LoginUser(request, response);
               try{
                   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                   if(request.getAttribute("result") == "success"){
                       json.put("result", "success");
                       json.put("id", user.getId());
                       json.put("name", user.getName());
                   } else {
                       json.put("result", "failure");
                       json.put("message", request.getAttribute("message"));
                   }
                   SendJSONResponse(json, request, response);
               }catch(Exception e){
               }
            } else {
                System.out.print("Unknown opt: " + action);
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void LoginUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = null;
    Long userId = (Long)session.getAttribute(USERID_ATTRIBUTENAME);
    if(userId != null){
        request.setAttribute("result", "failure");
        request.setAttribute("message", "The user is already logged in.");
    } else {
        final String email = request.getParameter("accountEmail");
        final String password = request.getParameter("accountPassword");
        if(email != null) {
            user = helperClass.magicallyGetUserByEmail(email);
            if(user != null){
                if(user.getPassword().equals(password)){
                    session.setAttribute(USERID_ATTRIBUTENAME, user.getId();
                    request.setAttribute("result", "success");
                }
            }
        } else {
           request.setAttribute("result", "failure");
        }
    }
    return user;
}

private void SendJSONResponse(JSONObject json, HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response) {
    String contentStr = json.toString();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.setContentLength(contentStr.length());
    response.getWriter().print(contentStr);
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

For reference purposes, this file is 1084 lines long. The doPost method is about 900 of those. Disclaimer: this is not my code. I did not write it. I only have to test it.
Now for the test:

```
//In MyFunServletTest.java:
//using JUnit 4

public class MyFunServletTest {
    static ServletTester tester;
    static String baseUrl;

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    User user;
    WebRequest loginRequest;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initClass(){
        tester = new ServletTester;
        tester.setContextPath("/");
        tester.addServlet(MyFunServlet.class, "/fun.service");
        baseUrl = tester.createSocketConnector(true);
        tester.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanClass() {
        tester.stop();
    }

    @Before
    public void preTest(){
        //taking values from our magical test user
        user = new User();
        user.setEmail("blah@blah.com");
        user.setPassword("secure");

        loginRequest = new WebRequest(baseUrl + "/fun.service", HttpMethod.POST);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new NameValuePair("opt","login"));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("accountEmail", user.getEmail());
        params.add(new NameValuePair("accountPassword", user.getPassword());
        loginRequest.setRequestParameters(params);

    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        WebResponse response = webClient.loadWebResponse(loginRequest);
        JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response.getContentAsString());

        //this test passes
        assertEquals("success", responseJSON.getString("result"));

        response = webClient.loadWebResponse(loginRequest);

        //this test fails
        assertTrue(404 != response.getStatusCode());

        //this then causes an error, as response.getContentAsString() is null.
        esponseJSON = new JSONObject(response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Help? Where am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the ability to run the test myself, I can only offer some approaches:

- Try creating *two* `JSONObject` objects to store the two responses separately, and compare the two (either print them or using the debugger), see if anything looks odd there.
- If that doesn't tell you anything, create two separate identical request instances and use each.
- Then try tracing through the call to `loadWebResponse` to see exactly what URL is being requested (cranking up the log level might tell you this, too).

If the 404 is correct, then the second request is somehow being mangled, but the question would be WHERE.

Comment: Another thing to try is to reduce testLogin() to just the first test that succeeds, then copy it as testLogin2() or such.   If doing the login twice in separate test methods works, then I'd think something is changing in your original request/response objects.   If the second login fails, however, then I'd suspect something is amiss with the site under test.